# Regex: how to match up to a character or the end of a line?

Tags: sed

I am trying to separate out parts of a path as follows. My input path takes the following possible forms:

```
bucket
bucket/dir1
bucket/dir1/dir2
bucket/dir1/dir2/dir3
...
```

I want to separate the first part of the path (`bucket`) from the rest of the string if present (`dir1/dir2/dir3/...`), and store both in separate variables.

The following gives me something close to what I want:

```bash
❯ BUCKET=$(echo "bucket/dir1/dir2" | sed 's@\(^[^\/]*\)[\/]\(.*\)@\1@')
❯ EXTENS=$(echo "bucket/dir1/dir2" | sed 's@\(^[^\/]*\)[\/]\(.*\)@\2@')
echo $BUCKET $EXTENS
❯ bucket dir1/dir2
```

HOWEVER, it fails if I only have `bucket` as input (without a slash):

```bash
❯ BUCKET=$(echo "bucket" | sed 's@\(^[^\/]*\)[\/]\(.*\)@\1@')
❯ EXTENS=$(echo "bucket" | sed 's@\(^[^\/]*\)[\/]\(.*\)@\2@')
echo $BUCKET $EXTENS
❯ bucket bucket
```

... because, in the absence of the first '/', no capture happens, so no substitution takes place. When the input is just `'bucket'` I would like `$EXTENS` to be set to the empty string `""`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something so simple you could use `bash` built-in instead of launching `sed`:

```bash
$ path="bucket/dir1/dir2"
$ bucket="${path%%/*}"
$ extens="${path#$bucket}"
$ printf '|%s|%s|\n' "$bucket" "$extens"
|bucket|/dir1/dir2|
$ path="bucket"
$ bucket="${path%%/*}"
$ extens="${path#$bucket}"
$ printf '|%s|%s|\n' "$bucket" "$extens"
|bucket||
```

But if you really want to use `sed` and capture groups:

```bash
$ declare -a bucket_extens
$ mapfile -td '' bucket_extens < <(printf '%s' "bucket/dir1/dir2" | sed -E 's!([^/]*)(.*)!\1\x00\2!')
$ printf '|%s|%s|\n' "${bucket_extens[@]}"
|bucket|/dir1/dir2|
$ mapfile -td '' bucket_extens < <(printf '%s' "bucket" | sed -E 's!([^/]*)(.*)!\1\x00\2!')
$ printf '|%s|%s|\n' "${bucket_extens[@]}"
|bucket||
```

We use the extended regex (`-E`) to simplify a bit, and `!` as separator of the substitute command. The first capture group is simply anything not containing a slash and the second is everything else, including nothing if there's nothing else.

In the replacement string we separate the two capture groups with a NUL character (`\x00`). We then use `mapfile` to assign the result to bash array `bucket_extens`.

The NUL trick is a way to deal with file names containing spaces, newlines... NUL is the only character that cannot be part of a file name. The `-d ''` option of `mapfile` indicates that the lines to map are separated by NUL instead of the default newline.

Comment: Thanks. I did consider this, but then I became obsessed with better understanding the regex-capture approach

Comment: OK, I added an example of use of `sed` and capture groups. Hope it helps your understanding.

Comment: Actually, I tried your first built-in approach and couldn't get extens to equal "" when path is set to just "bucket" (as described in my original specification) -- could you please add how you would do that with the first approach?

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that you also wanted the trailing part. I updated my answer.

Comment: Great -- thanks! Note: I think you meant to switch up the input strings in your two sed runs, and you're missing a trailing ')'

Comment: Oops, you're right. Fixed.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet nice use of build-ins +1. FYI here's [a way simpler regex approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72694404/256196) that doesn't need NUL, `-E` or any brackets etc

Comment: @Bohemian Sure, but it doesn't use capture group, something the OP apparently want to experiment with.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet my solution answers the question according to the title, as does your built-in solution.

Answer (score 1):

Don't capture anything. Instead, just match what you *don't* want and replace it with nothing:

```
BUCKET=$(echo "bucket" | sed 's@/.*@@').          # bucket
BUCKET=$(echo "bucket/dir1/dir2" | sed 's@/.*@@') # bucket

EXTENS=$(echo "bucket" | sed 's@[^/]*@@')           # blank
EXTENS=$(echo "bucket/dir1/dir2" | sed 's@[^/]*@@') # /dir1/dir2
```

Comment: Thanks. I did consider this, but then I became obsessed with better understanding the capture approach

Answer (score 0):

As you are putting a slash in the regex. the string with no slashes will not
match. Let's make the slash optional as `/\?`. (A backslash before `?`
is requires due to the sed `BRE`.) Then would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

#path="bucket/dir1/dir2"
path="bucket"
bucket=$(echo "$path" | sed 's@\(^[^/]*\)/\?\(.*\)@\1@')
extens=$(echo "$path" | sed 's@\(^[^/]*\)/\?\(.*\)@\2@')
echo "$bucket" "$extens"
```

- You don't need to prepend a backslash to a slash.
- By convention, it is recommended to use lower cases for user variables.

Comment: This isn't quite what I want. When path="bucket" the echo cmd prints "bucket bucket", whereas I want extens to be set to an empty string